# jQuery setInterval to delay execution in a loop callback

Tags: jquery, delay, setinterval, sleep

I want to show every hidden row, but sleep 3 seconds between rows.

```
jQuery.each($('.main-table tbody tr:hidden'),
        function (i, el) {
        setInterval(function(){ 
            $(el).removeClass('hidden');
        }, 3000);
        });
```

The above sleeps only 3 seconds for the first time. The rest runs right away without pause.

Comment: The call to setInterval is not a blocking call which means that javascript executes the statement and then moves on (i.e. doesn't wait for the interval to expire before moving on the next loop iteration). So you are setting the interval once for each loop iteration but the loop is happening so fast that each interval is firing at the same time which makes them appear as if they are going at the same time. This is why the 'multiply by loop variable' works in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply with the iterator, otherwise they will all execute in 3 seconds as the each loop runs and completes immediately, it doesn't wait for the timeouts to go the next element in the loop.

```
jQuery.each($('.main-table tbody tr:hidden'), function (i, el) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(el).removeClass('hidden');
    }, i * 3000);
});
```

note that the first time `i` will be zero, and `0*3000 == 0`, so no timeout.
If you need a timeout on the first iteration, do `(i+1) * 3000`

Comment: This would setup a series of setIntervals in a loop, which themselves will execute repeatedly over time. If there were 20 tr:hidden tags, this would get you 20 timers running forever, accomplishing nothing. On smartphones this would be a needless waste of battery life.

Answer (score 1):

Although adeneo's answer works great, here is another no-loop approach, which may help somebody searching for a solution to similar problem:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
   var el =$('table tr.hidden:first');

   if(el.length > 0)
       el.removeClass('hidden');
   else
       clearInterval(intervalID); // stop timer if no elements left
}, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gd6gn/

Comment: I think it should be setTimout or will run forever, no?

Comment: just updated my question, should have pushed "Update" button earlier, but you were quick to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) leverage jQuery's animation framework to do this.

```
var tbody = $('.main-table tbody');

tbody.find('tr:hidden').each(function(i, tr) {
    tbody.delay(3000)
    .queue(function(dequeue) {
        $(tr).removeClass('hidden');
        dequeue();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/54u154hc/

It avoids multiplying by leveraging existing code in the framework to clean that up for you, and it avoids a bug the other answers here all have where they're using setInterval in a loop, to do something setTimeout was meant to do. And both setInterval and setTimeout introduce a bug in newer browsers where the sequence will pause then surge ahead all at once if the tab is suspended to save CPU by the browser. This avoids that jarring surge of animation.